# AutoComplete textbox will not show suggestions

Tags: android, android-layout

No error in logcat, but the suggestion list will not show I am not sure where I went wrong. I have the autocomplete view inflated in an alert dialog box. Here is my code below

```
reg_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {


                final String[] devplatforms =
                     {
                     "C",
                     "C++",
                     "Java",
                     "iPhone",
                     "Android",
                     "ASP.NET",
                     "PHP",
                     "Python",
                     };


                AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(SettingsMain.this);
                LayoutInflater inflater = SettingsMain.this.getLayoutInflater(); 
                final View searchlayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_friend, null);

               adb.setView(searchlayout)

               .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {  
                        AutoCompleteTextView friend_name;
                        friend_name = (AutoCompleteTextView) searchlayout.findViewById(R.id.friend_name);
                        friend_name.setThreshold(1);
                        friend_name.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,devplatforms));

                        String name = friend_name.getText().toString();
                        Log.d( "ECHO" , "Pin Value : " + name);
                        return;                  
                       }  
                  })
               .setNegativeButton("Done", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {


                        dialog.cancel(); 
                    }
                }); 

                    adb.show();  

    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this code is in the wrong place:

```
AutoCompleteTextView friend_name;
friend_name = (AutoCompleteTextView) searchlayout.findViewById(R.id.friend_name);
friend_name.setThreshold(1);
friend_name.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,devplatforms));
```

Move it above this line:

```
adb.setView(searchlayout)
```

You inflated the layout, but you are only passing the AutoCompleteTextView an Adapter in your "Ok" Button... Set up the AutoCompleteTextView *before* displaying the Dialog.

Comment: wow, this is really rock bottom. I need to get back my focus and wash my face with some ice water and get back to work lol. Thanks for the simple correction also for explaining the situation.